# Get totals of friends in one query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the total of friends on one QUERY SQL

I have a table named `MEMBERS`, and this table have a `CALL_FRIEND_ID`,

the `CALL_FRIEND_ID` is a random ID you give it to your friend and if he/she register using, he/she become your friend by adding your to a column named `FRIEND_ID` (in the same table)

Now to know the total friend of each one I make two query

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBERS;
```

second

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MEMBERS WHERE FRIEND_ID = :id
```

but that make the response slowly

I try to use `HAVING` but without any result, any solution ?

Comment: What RBMS are you using? How many records do you have in `MEMBERS`? Could you provide some sample data? Do you have an index on your `FRIEND` column? That might be what you need...

Comment: @Zack do you mean sir with RBMS the type of DB ? is MySQL, in `Members` I have `FNAME,LNAME, EMAIL,PASSWORD`, and `FRIEND` content the `CALL_FRIEND_ID` id of the person that give hem the URL

Comment: Is your `:id` param a value in the `FRIEND_ID` column or `CALL_FRIEND_ID` column? Again, some sample data would really help here.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using 5.x or 8.0? The answer greatly depends on the version.

Comment: Please post the full `CREATE TABLE` statement (including foreign-key constraints), and please explain how your system works when a user has multiple friends.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: from your scenario I guess this'll give your desired output

```
 select FRIEND_ID,count(CALL_FRIEND_ID) as totalFriends from MEMBERS 
    where FRIEND_ID = :id
    group by FRIEND_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said when a member register then a random number is assigned to his or her that CALL_FRIEND_ID ,and you want total number of friends in your member table according to group wise of FRIEND_ID so there is need where clause,because where will be applicable if you find any specific FRIEND_ID, so you can use below query

```
select FRIEND_ID,count(CALL_FRIEND_ID) as totalFriends from MEMBERS 
        group by FRIEND_ID
```